# how to create transparent background image from existing image?

Tags: css, image

I have an image below but it's not transparent background, actually the background color is white. How to make it a transparent background? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: A Google search for "make image background transparent" found over 5 million hits - for example [http://www.angelfire.com/nm/thehtmlsource/jazzup/image/transparent.html]

Answer (score 0):

Try [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/), use "Magic Wand" tool and delete.

5 sec later:

[image]